# Is my congregational prayer invalid if a person walks in front of me?

Tags: salat

So today in the mosque I arrived 2 ruk'as late for Asr prayer, when the imam finished I started to complete the remainder, during this time a guy decided to cross in front of me, I know it will invalidate my prayer if I was praying on my own, but does this ruling apply in case of congregational/group prayers (in my case I had to complete the two ruk'as alone during which this guy walked in front of me) would my prayer be invalid and will I have to say my Asr prayer again?

> The Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) forbade that and said: “If the one who walks in front of a person who is praying knew (the sin) that is upon him, standing for forty would be better for him than passing in front of someone who is praying.” And he enjoined the one who is praying facing something to screen him from the people not to let anyone walk in front of him; rather he should stop him. He (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “If one of you prays facing something to screen him from the people, if someone wants to walk in front of him, let him push him away, and if he insists then let him fight him, for he is no more than a devil”

Comment: Didn't have enough time to stop him from passing as i was concentrating and he was fast!!

Answer (score 2):

prayer is valid if some one unconciously passes infront of you while you are praying... but if some one do so, you can stop him by hand as there is no sin in stoping and your salah is not broken(and you must do that).... it just breaks the concentration but one had to bulid it immediately... and i'll give hadith related to it after searching...
JazakAllah...

Answer (score 1):

No sure it is valid,
The point of prevent people to walk in front of you is to stay focus.

Answer (score -2):

Why is it an issue? You have to focus on your prayer for fullest and not what is happening in your surroundings. When you pray outside on the street, people will always pass in front of you. Should you tell them to stop until you have finished your prayer????